# How to use a third party Objective C library in Titanium development?

Tags: cross-platform, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I have a mobile project need to use a third party library, I want to use Titanium on both iOS and android, but the library is only written in Objective C.

There is a post from Appcelerator: [*Extending Titanium Mobile*](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Extending_Titanium_Mobile)

It seems need to rewrite the code but it is quite complicated.

Are there any other ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what library it is, or any details, I would say no, there is absolutely no way around this.

Things written in Obj-C, run on iOS, things written in JAVA run on Android. Therefore, you have to write something in JAVA for your module to work on Android.

As for porting your existing Obj-C library to Titanium, that is generally very trivial and is described in detail in the docs you linked too.

On another note, if your library can be implemented in JavaScript, then I would rewrite it in JavaScript as opposed to rewriting it for android, this would give you more platform ability.